# get html dynamically from partial page and put it into element in a page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-ajax

This is how I call ajax

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "/MyController/GetAll?Id=" + id,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
             $.each(result.data)
               {
             //in this code, I want to generate a table and it's dynamic  
               }
            }
```

Inside `$.each` of the result, I want to loop through the result and generate a table with data.  Currently, I add table as string like

```
           var myTable = '';
           myTable += '<table class="table table-stripe">';
           myTable += '<tr><td>' + this.name + '</td></tr>';
           ......
           ......
```

and at the end, I put this table like

```
           $('#sectionForTable').html(myTable);
```

But I don't like this method that generates table as a string and put it inside  `#sectionForTable`.  Because If I want to customize this table's CSS classes, styles or events of components inside this table, it will have to write a very complex string.
So, my question is, is there any way better than that?  Like write this table's code inside some cshtml partial page, call this page, get HTML and set the dynamic values. I just want to reduce code complexity.

Comment: The way you're doing it now, ie. looping through concatenating a string and then appending that content to the DOM once when the loop is finished, is just about the most performant way. Sure you could change it, but the best approach would depend on how many classes you add, how many elements are being amended, and the logic used to determine if the classes should be added.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , this is just a sample table . Actually, the table has more than 8 columns and each column has different css styles. In each column, there are buttons with click event, input with on change event.   Building this table over string concatenating become so complex.

Comment: Neither of those are a reason for more complicated HTML. `the table has more than 8 columns and each column has different css styles` Use CSS `:nth-child`. `there are buttons with click event, input with on change event` use a single delegated event handler for each event in your JS.